# Adjacency list implementation

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to implement a simple adjacency list. I understand that the index of the array is a key for the vertex at that point.

For Example:
If i had edges of the format: (start, finish, cost)
(1,2,4)
(2,3,5)
(1,3,27)
(3,4,8)

I would have an array that would be

### [0] -> null

### [1] -> 2|4 -> 3|27 -> null

### [2] -> 3|5 -> null

### [3] -> 4|8 -> null

One issue is that the container holding the edges has pointers but the elements inserted into them (edges) do not. I'm lost.

editing this post because I don't know how to put code in the comments.

```
struct Node{
       Edge *head;
       Node *next;
}

Node *root;

void adjacencyList::insert(const Edge &edge)
{

  if(root == NULL)
   {
      root = new Node;
      root->head = edge;
    }
  else
    {
      while(root != NULL)
        {          
          root = root->next;
          if(root == NULL);
          {
            root = new Node;
            root->head = edge;
            root = root ->next;

          }
        }
     }
}
```

The edge object has 3 properties(source, destination, cost)
Right now this does nothing but keep adding edges in a linked list. How can i separate the lists by the source?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You need to provide some of your code, specifically what is confusing you.

Comment: I don't know how to post code in comments so I edited the post. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adjacency list doesn’t have to be a linked list. Even if it were, *do not* implement an (intrusive) linked list yourself, use an existing implementation.

But here we go; just have a vector of (node, cost) pairs:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> weighted_node_t;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<weighted_node_t>> graph_t;
```

Then you can represent your graph as follows (using C++11 initialisation syntax):

```
graph_t graph{
    {},
    {{2, 4}, {3, 27}},
    {{3, 5}},
    {{4, 8}}
};
```

Now let’s assume you wanted to traverse the graph (depth first search), you’d do the following (again, C++11 syntax because it’s cleaner):

```
void dfs(graph_t const& graph, std::vector<bool>& visited, int node) {
    visited[node] = true;
    for (auto const& neighbor : graph[node])
        if (not visited[neighbor])
            dfs(graph, visited, neighbor.first);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
std::vector<bool> visited(graph.size());
dfs(graph, visited, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not familiar with pair but I'm going to try this. Is it possible to traverse the graph with this implementation? For example: if a vertex has two or more neighbors how do I get to them. In this case it would be {3,27}. Is it graph_t[1][1].weighted_node_t?

Comment: It’s just an array of arrays. In order to traverse it you’d access the index. Wait, let me add an example.

Comment: Thanks Konrad but do I have to statically assign my graph like the example that you give because i'm trying to put values into graph_t[1] and it's giving me errors (no match for operator). If i understand this correctly the vector graph_t contains pair objects. If i do a graph_t[0] = make_pair(1,2). then graph_t[0].first should be 1 and so forth.

Comment: @user2205018 The graph is dynamically modifiable. It’s just using the standard vector (it’s nested though!). So your code should be `graph[0].push_back(make_pair(1, 2));`. Read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and get a book on C++ programming to learn how to use that.

Comment: Thank you very much I was looking at the documentation and it wasn't making sense till i actually typed out the example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If I want the graph nodes to have properties, i.e. say I want each node to have a color {BLACK / WHITE} ... How would this be modified? In many of these basic implementations, the graph nodes have nothing other than a node number.

Comment: @WilderField In my example the nodes are called `weighted_node_t` because I gave each node a weight/cost, which is the second component of each adjacency list pair (the first element of the pair is the target node, since each entry in an adjacency list represents an edge in the graph. You can replace the second data member(type) by whatever you like, e.g. a colour.

Comment: @KonradRudolph your `weighted_node_t` type really constitutes an edge.... where you have an edge represented by a (destinationVertex, weight) pair. You don't have any properties associated with each Vertex. I've been working on my own code examples, and I have been able to use code similar to yours, and keep separate arrays to store vertex data...

Comment: @WilderField You are absolutely right! Apologies, it had been too long since I wrote the code. Yes, having a separate array is the canonical solution to storing node meta-information, and is in most cases very efficient. If the lack of cache locality becomes a problem you can replace the simple `int` representation of nodes with a dedicated class, but then you have to replace the outer vector in the adjacency list with a dictionary type (e.g. an `unordered_map`) and that has its own performance implications.